# Read and Write Int using ByteBuffer in Java NIO

Tags: java, networking, nio, bytebuffer, data-conversion

I want to transmit an int array over a network using Datagram Channel in Java NIO API. However, the functions read/write can only take a `ByteBuffer` as an input. So I need to store the int data to a `ByteBuffer` and then read it back at the receiver. I am facing the `java.nio.BufferUnderflowException`. Here is what I do at the Sender Side:

```
for(i = 0; i < send_data.length; i++)
{
          //Write the data onto Buffer
          ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(send_data[i].length*4);
          for(j = 0; j < send_data[i].length; j++)
                     buffer1.putInt(send_data[i][j]);
          buffer1.flip();
          //Transmit the data
          while(buffer1.hasRemaining())
                 channel.write(buffer1);
}
```

Here, `send_data` is a 2D array where each row is treated as a separate data packet.

At the Receiver Side

```
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
           ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((recvpkt[0].length)*4);
           channel.receive(buffer);
           j = 0;
           while(buffer.hasRemaining())
           {
                  recvpkt[i][j] = buffer.getInt();
                  j = j+1;
           }
 }
```

Similarly, `recvpkt` is a 2D array and each row of it will receive one packet from the network.

I read that `getInt()` reads 4 bytes from the `ByteBuffer` and moves the current position by 4 bytes. Is it that I am using the `buffer.flip()` in a wrong manner. I am new to using `NIO` and am having difficulty in how to go about debugging such issues.

UPDATE:

The error no longer occurs. But now all that the Receiver gets is all zeros. Whereas I am transmitting a binary sequence in each packet. When I read back from the buffer at the Sender side itself, all the entries turn up correctly but the buffer received at Receiver side has all zeros. No idea why this is happening.

UPDATE 2:

Finally, after hours of struggling, the problem is fixed. When you receive the buffer , you need to rewind it.

```
  channel.receive(buffer);
  buffer.rewind();
```

If you now use the getInt method on the buffer, you will be able to read the buffer successfully.

Comment: This is about as inefficient as you could possibly make it. You should be allocating a *single* ByteBuffer, storing *all* the data in it, and then using your write loop to send it all.

Comment: point taken .. but currently I want to understand why I am getting the above mentioned exception. I mean, efficiency apart, is there anything wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have th flip() the buffer each time you swap from write to read and from read to writing. Add flip() to the second example after `receive()`

Once you have this working you should look at how you can re-use your ByteBuffers and EJP suggests.

Comment: flip sets the current position of the buffer to be its limit and the current position is set to 0. Wouldn't flipping again at receiver side cause problems ? I mean, I write a packet to the buffer in one go, flip the buffer and then read it. So why should flip happen again while reading ?

Comment: In both cases you write to the buffer and the position has the point it has written up to. Then you need to read from the start up to the point which was written.  The only difference between the two examples is who does the writing and who does the reading, but you need a flip between them in both cases.

Comment: Despite its (stupid) name, flip() is not the inverse of itself. You must flip before writing or getting, and compact() or clear() afterwards.

Comment: If you compact() or clear(), you don't need to flip() as well as it does that for you.

Comment: No it doesn't. It's not a reversible operation. It would be more correct to say that flip() readies the buffer for writing or getting, and compact() and clear() make the buffer ready for reading or putting. If you just use flip() instead of compact() or clear() it doesn't work.